# best way to invoke a class method dynamically in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have controller "MyController" which has a class method "my_controller_class_method" which accepts arguments a,b,c

is there a way to pass "MyController.my_controller_class_method" as an argument to another method so I could do something like that:

```
def use_another_method(other_method,a,b,c)
  #invoke method inside
   other_method(a,b,c)
end
```

and then I could run

```
use_another_method(MyController.my_controller_class_method,a1,b1,c1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.method` to get an object representing that method:

```rb
method_object = MyController.method(:my_controller_class_method)
method_object.call(a, b, c)
method_object.(a, b, c)      # shorter syntax
```

That object can then be passed around and used as a function argument, just like any other object.

Comment: ...or use `public_send`.